# Typescript unable to find Express module

Tags: node.js, express, typescript

I am trying to create my first NodeJS application, however I couldn't make it work.

These are the steps I followed so far from various blogs and trying to build first nodejs app in typescript.

```
npm install -g express-generator
npm install -g typescript
express SampleApp
npm install -g typings
typings install dt~node --global
typings install dt~express dt~serve-static dt~express-serve-static-core --global
cd SampleApp
npm install
```

hello.ts

```
import express = require('express');
var app = express();
```

When I build compile the ts file with TypeScript

```
>>> tsc -m commonjs -t es5 hello.ts
hello.ts(1,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'express'.
```

I have gone through various resources, couldn't find the solution.
I guess I don't have to copy node.d.ts and express.d.ts files manually to the project folder.

If I use nodejs and expressjs alone `npm start` it works fine. `Typescript` plugin is something I am not able to do

Can anyone help what exactly I am doing wrong here?

Comment: No experience with TS whatsoever, but generally, after running `express SampleApp` you need to run `npm install` in the generated project directory.

Comment: cd SampleApp then npm install

Comment: @arjunkori, I have done that. I am new to nodejs however I know little basics of installing packages and running things. Just trying to plugin "TypeScript"

Comment: is there any reason why you are installing the typings globally? :)

Comment: @toskv, it suggested me to install global and VS Code official blog, so i just went ahead and done that :)

Comment: make sure the .d.ts files are present in the somewhere in your project structure. Also speaking of project, make a tsconfig.json and configure tsc that way so it considers the entire folder. I don't know if it will look for typings if you tell it to compile the only 1 file.

Comment: you can just run **tsc --init** in your folder. After that you should be able to just run **tsc** in the console.

Comment: @toskv, do I need to download .d.ts files explicitly and keep them in project folder. I am just thinking what's the point of so many npm packages? one package could have delivered/automated this

Comment: that's what the typings utility is for. to download the .d.ts files and keep them in your project. it does all the --save stuff you'd expect. The alternative is for the node_modules you are using to contain .d.ts files themselves but that's less common.

Comment: @toskv, `typings install express` is supposed to do this. however it's complaining that's been installed global and can't install local package. I am just going mad over this global local thing :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112672/discussion-between-reddy-and-toskv).

Comment: uninstall it globally and install it locally. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this issue by uninstalling `typings` package and reinstall `typings` with --global --save

```
1. npm uninstall typings --global
2. npm install typings --global
3. typings install dt~node dt~express --global --save
```

then typescript files are getting compiled fine.

Reported Issue: https://github.com/typings/typings/issues/543

Comment: Does not work for me. Followed steps 1-3 and even removed the entries in my Program Files(86)\Microsoft SDKS\Typescript folder. I'm using TS 1.8.

Comment: install `typescript` using `npm install typescript -g`

Comment: Tried that, and then steps 1-3 again. tsc app.ts still cannot find express using a typescript import statement like import * as express from 'express'.

Comment: created new project, setup same way and using typescript 2.1. Same issue. Typescript installed global as well.

Comment: Got it working. Reinstalled all node modules. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The typescript doesn't contain the type description for express, that has to be added using the below

```
npm i @types/express
```